# How can I get a scalar Balance

Tags: sqlite

To compute the beginning ledger balance, I've this query:

```
select
    case when DrControl = 7 then sum(Amount) end Debit,
    case when CrControl = 7 then sum(Amount) end Credit
from Transactions
where 7 in (DrControl, CrControl)
and Date < '2020-05-31'
group BY DrControl --, CrControl
```

and it returns two row:

```
Debit       Credit
------------------
900000      NULL
NULL        40000
```

I've to compute balance by subtracting one from the other in my Application code. What I really need in this case is Debit - Credit (900000 - 40000) = 860000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `group by ...`, just conditional aggregation:

```
select
    sum(case when DrControl = 7 then Amount end) -
    sum(case when CrControl = 7 then Amount end) 
from Transactions
where 7 in (DrControl, CrControl) and Date < '2020-05-31'
```

Just in case there are no rows with `DrControl = 7` or `CrControl = 7` use also `COALESCE()` to return `0` instead of `null`:

```
select
    coalesce(sum(case when DrControl = 7 then Amount end), 0) -
    coalesce(sum(case when CrControl = 7 then Amount end), 0) 
from Transactions
where 7 in (DrControl, CrControl) and Date < '2020-05-31'
```

Comment: Looks like this conditional aggregation will simplify my computation of balances for the Balance sheet as well.